# Which Quran verses mention the sahaba/companions?

Tags: sahaba, ayah

I am looking for verses in the `Quran` that mention the `companions` of the prophet Mohamed.
 Can anyone help me find these verses?

Comment: Do you mean by name? By name, only one companion is mentioned in whole of Qur'an. Zaid bin Harithah (radiyallahu 'anhu) in 37th Verse of Surah al-Ahzaab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By name, as the answer and comment above indicate, it was only Zaid (RA). Generally, all of them in this verse:

> Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah ; and those with him are forceful against the disbelievers, merciful among themselves. You see them bowing and prostrating [in prayer], seeking bounty from Allah and [His] pleasure. Their mark is on their faces from the trace of prostration. That is their description in the Torah. And their description in the Gospel is as a plant which produces its offshoots and strengthens them so they grow firm and stand upon their stalks, delighting the sowers - so that Allah may enrage by them the disbelievers. Allah has promised those who believe and do righteous deeds among them forgiveness and a great reward.

[(Holy Qur'an 48:29)](http://quran.com/48/29)

Answer (score 3):

Yes zaid is the one mentioned in Quran. Have a read at this ayah

> **وَإِذْ تَقُولُ لِلَّذِي أَنْعَمَ اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ  وَأَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِ أَمْسِكْ عَلَيْكَ زَوْجَكَ وَاتَّقِ اللَّهَ وَتُخْفِي فِي
>   نَفْسِكَ مَا  اللَّهُ مُبْدِيهِ وَتَخْشَى النَّاسَ وَاللَّهُ أَحَقُّ
>   أَن تَخْشَاهُ ۖ فَلَمَّا قَضَىٰ **زَيْدٌ مِّنْهَا وَطَرًا
>   زَوَّجْنَاكَهَا لِكَيْ لَا يَكُونَ عَلَى الْمُؤْمِنِينَ حَرَجٌ فِي
>   أَزْوَاجِ أَدْعِيَائِهِمْ إِذَا قَضَوْا مِنْهُنَّ وَطَرًا ۚ وَكَانَ
>   أَمْرُ اللَّهِ مَفْعُولًا******
>
> And [remember, O Muhammad], when you said to the one on whom Allah
>   bestowed favor and you bestowed favor, "Keep your wife and fear
>   Allah," while you concealed within yourself that which Allah is to
>   disclose. And you feared the people, while Allah has more right that
>   you fear Him. So when ***Zayd*** had no longer any need for her, We
>   married her to you in order that there not be upon the believers any
>   discomfort concerning the wives of their adopted sons when they no
>   longer have need of them. And ever is the command of Allah
>   accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

The verse 9:100 of the Quran is acknowledged as the strongest verse which praises the Muhajireen and the Ansaar Sahabas and declares that Allah is pleased with them due to their sacrifices for Islam. The suffix radiallahu Anhu also derived from this verse:

> And the first forerunners [in the faith] among the Muhajireen and the Ansar and those who followed them with good conduct - Allah is pleased with them and they are pleased with Him, and He has prepared for them gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein they will abide forever. That is the great attainment.

Answer (score 1):

Asalam o AlieKum :
This story is mentioned in the Quran in SURAH TAUBA CH: 9 V Allah says:�
“If you will not aid him (the Prophet), Allah certainly aided him when those who disbelieved expelled him; he (the Prophet) had no more than him, him being the second of the two (i.e. Abu Bakr), when they were both in the cave, when he (the Prophet) said to his companion (Abu Bakr): ‘Grieve not, surely Allah is with US.’ Then Allah caused His Sakinah (serenity, peace, tranquility, etc.) to descend upon him (Abu Bakr)” (Quran, 9:40)

Sadaq ALLAH ul Azeem

Answer (score 0):

Kindly also see this verse:

“Allah was well pleased with the believers when they swore allegiance unto thee beneath the tree, and He knew what was in their hearts, and He sent down peace of reassurance on them, and hath rewarded them with a near victory” [48:18]

Answer (score 0):

As Salamo Alaikum Wa Rahmatullah Wa Barkatuhu
سورة الأنبياء Verse 101/102/103
سورة الفتح Verse 18/29
سورة التوبة Verse 40/100

Comment: Welcome to islam.stackexchange. It would be nice to either cite directly or to link, e.g. to https://tanzil.net/#9:40 to help finding the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum. There was an encounter of the Prophet (SAW) with Abdullah ibn Umm Maktum (RA) (Umm Maktum meaning mother of the concealed one as Abdullah (RA) was blind) that is mentioned in the Quran, however not by name. This is Surah Abasa (He frowned) which describes when the Prophet (SAW) was inviting Quraysh leaders to Islam and turned away from the blind companion who had asked him to recite from the Quran. Because of this, Allah (SWT) revealed the surah informing us how we should not treat people worse because of their standing in society.